# Documentation for Natvis customized view

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pretty-print

I need to write a Natvis file to help debug programs using my own hash table. I have searched the internal files of Visual Studio 2015, and I found this for the `std::unordered_map`:

```
<Type Name="std::unordered_map&lt;*&gt;" Priority="MediumHigh" ExcludeView="ShowElementsByIndex">
    <DisplayString>{_List}</DisplayString>
    ...
    <Expand>
        ...
        <ExpandedItem>_List,view(MapHelper)</ExpandedItem>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

I cannot find any documentation on how to use this `view(MapHelper)`? Any idea on what it is?